# Counting max number of duplicates with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to see the maximum number of duplicates for any record.

I've tried to use groupby for the ID that may be duplicated, and then value_counts to count. However, I keep getting the wrong answer (2 but in excel it's 4). Is there any reason I'd be getting the wrong answer here or a better way to do this?

```py
ScoringSiteDataDF = ScoringSiteDataDF.groupby(['Exam+DBN+Section'])['Exam+DBN+Section'].value_counts().to_frame('count')
print("Maximum count: " + str(ScoringSiteDataDF['count'].max()))
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add some sample data (as text) and your expected output please?

Comment: the problem is not with code. It depends on your data.

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question in this case without sample data and an expected output. Please modify your question as per @cs95 or it might not be easy for others to answer your question. Thanks.

Comment: Is `df.groupby('x')['x'].value_counts()` giving you something you need rather than just `df['x'].value_counts()`?